# JavaScript/jQuery: Detecting whether or not a click was above the fold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

For firing a scroll animation, I would like to detect whether or not a click was made above the fold (i.e. in the initial viewport on the top of the page) or whether it was made after scrolling down past a certain point.

My initial approach to this was to try the `event.clientY` property, but that, I found out, is relative to the viewport and doesn't keep track of whether I have scrolled down or not.

Comment: Would you like to share some code you've written?

Comment: You can set a flag at the .scroll function so that you can keep track if the scroll has occurred or not

`$( "#YOUR_SCROLL_IS" ).scroll(function() {
 // set a flag here
});`